# cambiar icono cuando el acordeon está collapse o no

Tags: html5, typescript, scss

estoy intentando cambiar la clase del icono 'oi-plus' del acordeón cuando está collapse, debe de aparecer la clase 'oi-plus' y cuando esté desplegado, debe cambiar por 'oi-minus'

**HTML**

```
<div id="accordion">
        <div class="card">
          <div class="card-header" id="headingOne">
            <h5 class="mb-0">
              <button class="btn btn-link btn-block" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne">
                Lifestyle Habits <span class="oi oi-plus ic-plus"></span>
              </button>
            </h5>
          </div>

          <div id="collapseOne" class="collapse show" aria-labelledby="headingOne" data-parent="#accordion">
            <div class="card-body">
              <ul class="interior">
                <li>
                  <input type="checkbox" name="habits" id="intellectual">
                  <span class="txt-checkbox">Intellectual Habits</span>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <input type="checkbox" name="habits" id="sportive">
                  <span class="txt-checkbox">Sportive Habits</span>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <input type="checkbox" name="habits" id="smoking">
                  <span class="txt-checkbox">Smoking</span>
                </li>
                <li>
                <input type="checkbox" name="habits" id="gambling">
                <span class="txt-checkbox">Gambling problems</span>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <input type="checkbox" name="habits" id="aedentary">
                  <span class="txt-checkbox">Sedentary habits</span>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <input type="checkbox" name="habits" id="adequate">
                  <span class="txt-checkbox">Adequate Sleep</span>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <input type="checkbox" name="habits" id="computer">
                  <span class="txt-checkbox">Computer Addiction</span>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <input type="checkbox" name="habits" id="drug">
                  <span class="txt-checkbox">Drug Addiction</span>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <input type="checkbox" name="habits" id="alcoholic">
                  <span class="txt-checkbox">Alcoholic</span>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="card">
          <div class="card-header" id="headingTwo">
            <h5 class="mb-0">
              <button class="btn btn-link btn-block collapsed" name="list" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseTwo" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseTwo">
                Dietary Habits <span class="oi oi-plus ic-plus"></span>
              </button>
            </h5>
          </div>
          <div id="collapseTwo" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="headingTwo" data-parent="#accordion">
            <div class="card-body">
              <ul class="interior">
                <li>
                  <input type="checkbox" name="habits" id="intellectual">
                  <span class="txt-checkbox">Intellectual Habits</span>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <input type="checkbox" name="habits" id="sportive">
                  <span class="txt-checkbox">Sportive Habits</span>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <input type="checkbox" name="habits" id="smoking">
                  <span class="txt-checkbox">Smoking</span>
                </li>
                <li>
                <input type="checkbox" name="habits" id="gambling">
                <span class="txt-checkbox">Gambling problems</span>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <input type="checkbox" name="habits" id="aedentary">
                  <span class="txt-checkbox">Sedentary habits</span>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <input type="checkbox" name="habits" id="adequate">
                  <span class="txt-checkbox">Adequate Sleep</span>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <input type="checkbox" name="habits" id="computer">
                  <span class="txt-checkbox">Computer Addiction</span>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <input type="checkbox" name="habits" id="drug">
                  <span class="txt-checkbox">Drug Addiction</span>
                </li>
                <li>
                  <input type="checkbox" name="habits" id="alcoholic">
                  <span class="txt-checkbox">Alcoholic</span>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

**SCSS**

```
    & .card {
    background-color: transparent;
    background-clip: unset;
    border: 0;
    border-radius: 0;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #001a5a;
    margin-left: 20px;
    width: 260px;
  }
  & .card-header {
    padding: 0 1.25rem;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    background-color: transparent;
    border-bottom: 0;
  }
  & .btn-link {
    font-weight: normal;
    color: #fff;
    background-color: transparent;
    text-decoration: none;
    & :hover{
      color: #fff;
      text-decoration: none;
      background-color: transparent;
      border-color: transparent;
    }
    & :focus{
      text-decoration: none;
      border-color: transparent;
      box-shadow: none;
    }
  }
  & .btn-link.focus {
    text-decoration: none;
    border-color: transparent;
    box-shadow: none;
      & :hover{
        color: #fff;
        text-decoration: none;
        background-color: transparent;
        border-color: transparent;
      }
  }

  & .btn-link {
    font-weight: normal;
    color: #fff;
    background-color: transparent;
    text-align: left;
  }
  & .ic-plus{
    font-size: 12px;
    position: relative;
    float: right;
    margin-top: 5px;
  }
```

No sé si se podrá hacer sólo con CSS en la forma en la que lo estoy haciendo si necesito algo de programación, sería con Typescript, ya se está programando con Angular 10

Comment: Si tienes el código donde se expande y contrae el acordeón puedes modificar el ícono desde ahí

Comment: El collapse del acordeon es una función de bootstrap que lo saqué de la web (https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/collapse/)

Comment: Si estás usando Bootstrap "vanilla", debes tomar en cuenta de que este está fuertemente basado en jQuery, en función de ello, creo que lo que buscas es un [toggler](https://www.jquery-az.com/boots/demo.php?ex=50.0_1). 

Por otro lado, tengo una duda, estás usando algún framework en particular?

Comment: yo estoy con la parte de maquetacion y la persona que hace el desarrollo front no me acuerdo si trabaja con Angular 10 o Angular 11